# Why does my inputAccessoryView disappear when navigating backwards?

Tags: ios, swift, first-responder, inputaccessoryview

I implemented an own inputAccessoryView within a VC that gets pushed by a `UINavigationController`.

This is how the VC looks like: Notice the inputAccessoryView at the bottom (the white bar with the button and a text field)

[image: 1]]

When I swipe from the left to the right of the screen (in order to dismiss the current VC and go back), the inputAccessoryView moves down and disappears. In addition, if I stop the swipe gesture anywhere and let the current VC jump back (so that it won't be dismissed), the inputAccessoryView also moves down and disappears.

I attached another photo while moving: 
[image: 2]]

An another one after the VC jumped back:

[image: 3]]

As you can see, the inputAccessoryView has disappeared.

My piece of code:

```
private final lazy var inputContainerView: UIView = {
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    [...]
    return containerView
}()
[...]


override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return inputContainerView
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Are you hiding tabbar when push to view controller?

Comment: Show your code for adding inputContainerView

Comment: I am hiding the tabbar. The code for adding the inputContainerView is already there. It‘s the accessory view. @JD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try calling

`self.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewWillAppear`or `viewDidAppear` both of them will be trigged when that happens.

Comment: Yup, that worked very well... xD Thanks a lot! Is there any simple explanation on what becomeFirstResponder() does?

Comment: `inputAccessoryView` will shown only when the object that its binding to `isFirstResponder` value is true. In this case that object is your viewController (that's why you override `canBecomeFirstResponder`). I'm not 100% sure but I think in this case when dragging action happen and cancelled, the first responder doesn't resigned back to this viewController properly... so we have to force it to happen.

Comment: `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
`

yes this worked for me